# EXISTS on two databases in one redis instance

Tags: redis

Given a redis instance containing two databases db1, db2:
Is it possible to query if `k1 \in db1 and k2 \in db2` in one transaction, i.e., a single request from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible if you use a Lua script.